# Writing a Low latency code in C/ C++ language that automatically take care of cache lines size

Tags: c++, c, performance, caching, cpu

How to write C/C++ code that takes care of the cache line alignment automatically.

Suppose we write an structure in c and have 5 members in to it and we want to align the this structures members to the different cache lines in different hardware X86 hardware CPU.

For example,  If I have two X86 machine Machine_1 and Machine_2.
And Machine_1 has 64 byte cache line and Machine_2 has 32 byte cache line.
How will I do a coding so that each variable will be aligns to different cache lines for both the Machine_1 and Machine_2.

```
struct test_cache_alignment {
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;

};
```

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: There is no platform-independent way of doing this.

Comment: Super-optimization and portability are very often conflicting goals. You need to pick one, or at least pick a balance between the two.

Answer (score 3):

This mostly breaks down into 2 separate problems.

The first problem is ensuring that the structure as a whole begins on a cache line boundary, which depends on where the structure is. If you allocate memory for the structure using `malloc()` then you need a `malloc()` that will ensure alignment. If you put a structure in global data then the compiler and/or linker has to ensure alignment. If you have a structure as local data (on the stack) then the compiler has to generate code that ensures alignment.

This is only partly solvable. You can write your own `malloc()` or write a wrapper around an existing `malloc()`. You might be able to have special sections that are aligned (instead of using the normal `.rodata`, `.data` and `.bss` sections) and convince the linker to do the right thing. You probably won't be able to get the compiler to generate suitably aligned local data.

The second part of the problem is ensuring that offsets of member within the structure are multiples of the cache line size. This means that if the structure as a whole is aligned then the members of the structure will also be aligned. This might not be so hard to do (as long as you don't mind "slightly not portable" code and painful micro-management). For example:

```
#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE    32

struct test_cache_alignment {
    int a;
    uint8_t padding1[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
    int b;
    uint8_t padding2[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
    int c;
    uint8_t padding3[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
    int d;
    uint8_t padding4[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
    int e;
    uint8_t padding5[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
};
```

However; for this specific case (a structure of integers) it's rare to want to waste space like this. Without the padding it would have all fit in a single cache line and spreading it across many cache lines will only increase cache misses and reduce performance.

The only case I can think of where you actually want to use a whole cache line is to reduce false sharing in multi-CPU systems (e.g. to avoid "cache line bouncing" caused by different CPUs modifying different members of the same structure at the same time). Often for these cases you're doing something wrong to begin with (e.g. maybe it's better to have separate local variables and not use a structure at all).

Comment: Thanks Brendan for such a clear guidelines. Yes my intention is to avoid the false sharing. could you please give small examples of aligning the structure based on where it is placed ( in all three cases) How to do that. ?